# MudImage doesn't rerender when it is changed

Tags: image, mudblazor

I have a pictured stored as /Images/cs.jpg

[image]

When I load my page, I see this picture perfectly.

[image]

```
<MudContainer MaxWidth="MaxWidth.Large">
<MudPaper Elevation="1" Class="ma-2 pa-2 mud-theme-secondary">
    <MudStack Row="true" AlignItems="AlignItems.Center" Justify="Justify.SpaceEvenly">
     <MudImage Src="@_picture" Height="200" Class="rounded-lg"  />
    </MudStack>
</MudPaper>
```

But when I change the picture to something else like this:

[image]

The picture isn't updated.
I tried a lot of different things: OnAfterRenderAsync, StateHasChanged, different ways to load/show the image, included a text or button to refresh it, ... but no luck.

I trimmed some code down:

```
@code
{
private string _picture;

protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
{
    _picture = "/Image/cs.jpg";
    //_picture = await ImageService["/Image/cs.jpg"];
    StateHasChanged();
}

private async Task UpdateLabelPreview()
{
        _picture = "/Image/cs.jpg";
        //_picture = await ImageService["/Image/cs.jpg"];
        StateHasChanged();

}
}
```

Any idea?

Comment: The examples are a bit unclear, how are you changing the images? Is something changing the same image file in your image service?

Comment: I am changing them through active-x.  That part is working fine, so that's why I didn't mentioned it.

Comment: Blazor WASM or Server?